# Pandas: неожиданное поведение DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Может я что-то делаю не так?

```
import pandas as pd, datetime
print(pd.__version__)
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,11,111],[2,22,222],[3,33,3333],[4,44,4444]],columns=['val','line1 (%)','line2 (%)'])
print(a)
print('-'*80)
a.loc[10] = {'val': pd.to_datetime(1583485200.0*1_000_000_000), 'line1 (%)': 97.0, 'line2 (%)': 100.0}
print(a)
print('-'*80)
data = {'val': datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1583485200.0), 'line1 (%)': 97.0, 'line2 (%)': 100.0}
a.loc[10] = data #<<<<<<<<<???????
print(a)
print('?'*80)
a.loc[10] = data
print(a)
print('!'*80)
```

Получаю результат:

```
Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============================================ RESTART: D:\!Project\test.py ============================================
1.0.1
   val  line1 (%)  line2 (%)
0    1         11        111
1    2         22        222
2    3         33       3333
3    4         44       4444
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    val  line1 (%)  line2 (%)
0                     1       11.0      111.0
1                     2       22.0      222.0
2                     3       33.0     3333.0
3                     4       44.0     4444.0
10  2020-03-06 09:00:00       97.0      100.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    val  line1 (%)  line2 (%)
0     1         11        111
1     2         22        222
2     3         33       3333
3     4         44       4444
10  val  line1 (%)  line2 (%)
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
                    val line1 (%) line2 (%)
0                     1        11       111
1                     2        22       222
2                     3        33      3333
3                     4        44      4444
10  2020-03-06 09:00:00        97       100
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Почему `a.loc[10]` присваивает первый раз значение, потом имена столбцов, а потом опять значение?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Присвоение строке DataFrame **словаря**, насколько мне известно, не является документированным способом.

Попробуйте присваивать *список* или `np.array(...)` значений:

```
In [22]: a.loc[10] = list(data.values())
```

результат:

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]:
                    val line1 (%) line2 (%)
0                     1        11       111
1                     2        22       222
2                     3        33      3333
3                     4        44      4444
10  2020-03-06 09:00:00        97       100
```

Comment: Так, конечно можно, но это при условии что порядок столбцов соответствует порядку ключей в словаре.